# C Structures: Printing a string member produces weird results

Tags: c, string, struct

I am independently learning C. I have a four member struct as follows:

```
#define aSize 10
struct Students {
     char lastName[aSize];
     char firstName[aSize];
     int age; 
     int grade;
 }
```

I have two separate functions (in the main.c file):

```
void pasteInfo_1(struct Students S1) {}
```

and

```
void printStudents(struct Students S1) {}
```

`pasteInfo()` uses `strcpy()` and assignment to assign values to the members; `printStudents()` then prints the values stored in the members. When I compile the file:

```
#in makefile
CFLAGS = -lm -o -Wall
gcc main.c $(CFLAGS) main
```

It compiles with no errors. However, when I call the executable it prints some very weird characters that look like binary/assembly. Any suggestions? Here are the individual functions.

```
void pasteInfo_1(struct Students S1) {
     strcpy(S1.lastName, "Effinger");
 }
```

And here is printStudents:

```
void printStudents(struct Students S1) {
     printf("%s\n",S1.lastName);
}
```

The function calls in main:

```
int main() {
     struct Students S1;
     pasteInfo_1(S1);
     printStudents(S1);
 }
```

Re: Modifications.
After adding the changes suggested by user3629249, I got the following errors:

```
main.c:6:23: warning: ‘struct Students’ declared inside parameter list      will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 void pasteInfo(struct Students * pS1);
                       ^~~~~~~~
main.c:7:27: warning: ‘struct Studens’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 void printStudents(struct Studens S1);
                           ^~~~~~~
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:22:14: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pasteInfo’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   pasteInfo( &S1);
              ^
main.c:6:6: note: expected ‘struct Students *’ but argument is of type ‘struct Students *’
 void pasteInfo(struct Students * pS1);
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:23:17: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
   printStudents(S1);
                 ^~
main.c: At top level:
main.c:26:6: error: conflicting types for ‘pasteInfo’
 void pasteInfo(struct Students * pS1)
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:6:6: note: previous declaration of ‘pasteInfo’ was here
 void pasteInfo(struct Students * pS1);
      ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:32:6: error: conflicting types for ‘printStudents’
 void printStudents(struct Students S1)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:7:6: note: previous declaration of ‘printStudents’ was here
 void printStudents(struct Studens S1);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it! Here is the working code:
(Special Thanks to user3629249 and Seb for their advice)

```
'#include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <strings.h>

 struct Students
 {
     char lastName[8];
     char firstName[6];
     int age;
     int grade;
 };

 void pasteInfo(struct Students *S1);
 void printStudnets(struct Students S1);

 int main(void)
 {

     struct Students S1;
     pasteInfo( &S1 );
     printStudents( S1 );
 }
 void pasteInfo(struct Students *S1)
 {
     strcpy(S1->lastName, "Effinger");
 }
 void printStudent(struct Students S1)
 {
      printf("%s\n",S1.lastName);
 }
```

Comment: this does not compile!   The prototype for `printStudent()` is not spelled correctly.

Comment: the strut field: `lastName` is only declared to be 8 characters, but the value being written into it is 9 characters (remember the trailing NUL byte) The overrunning of the `lastName` field results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: Thankfully, the actual .c does not have any typos.

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your error messages as though you need to forward declare `struct Students` and/or `pasteInfo`. See your textbook for advice on how to do that, if necessary.

> I am independently learning C.

What does this mean? Are you reading from a book? If so, which book?

Keep in mind that it's dangerous to learn C by misguided trial and error; what you'll most likely end up learning is something that differs from C in subtle and possibly dangerous ways, and which medications best deal with the headaches you give yourself...

That's the peril of learning by misguided trial and error; you'll run into a lot of undefined behaviour (and implementation-defined behaviour) that will differ from system to system and might not make sense at the time...

You're better off avoiding UB and IB by reading a decent book such as K&R2E, and doing the exercises as you stumble across them.

Comment: "*Keep in mind that it's dangerous to learn C by misguided trial and error*' -- I'd just like to point out that that's pretty much how I taught myself C as a kid, and I'd like to think I turned out alright in the end anyway. Not saying I'd recommend the method, just saying. :)

Comment: @Dolda2000 Likewise, though I later came back to a book (and the C standard), and regretted not using them to begin with. My studies would have progressed so much more quickly!

Comment: Well... My grandfather is giving me "projects" (write a code that does this and this). Return the struct, and then print it. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan Ahh, grandfathers. Cherish that relationship; you won't regret it. A question to perhaps pose to your grandfather: Should it be possible to have a *negative* age? ;)

Comment: @ndim most c/c++ programmers have learn their best tricks, if not all of their skills by trial and errot, so don't pay top much attention to thé naysayers, and have fun learning the basics  following your original plan.

Comment: @Michaël Roy it appears you may still have some of those nonportable "best tricks" to iron out... note the keyword _misguided_ trial and error, such as neglecting to point out the common error in `ispunct(b[i])` that OP also neglected to spot because they've never seen the idiomatic cast, `ispunct((unsigned char) b[i])`... Maybe, just maybe, you might need to learn from a book written by an expert to avoid these subtle yet devastating issues from permeating throughout an entire companies portfolio, before the damage to the business and your own career is too great...

Comment: @autistic  I only have abput 40 years of experience in programming.  I actually stared programming in 1984,  at a time who when the ONLY way to go forward was trial and error.  Any decent team leader will tell you that developers who never try out stuff on their own volition do not learn as fast and don 't turn out to be god programmers.

Comment: @Michaël Roy I don't mean to push aside your experience, but the solution to this problem in particular is so clear to anyone who has read a textbook (OP needs to forward declare `struct Students` and/or `pasteInfo`, by the looks of the error messages). Perhaps for some entirely new field of programming, you may have a point, but at this stage we're dealing with the basics, and there are textbooks designed to guide students seamlessly past this hurdle (and many, many others) written by people who are far more credible (and authoritative) than you. If you believe otherwise, write a book...

Comment: @autistic  He's teaching himself, with hopefully the help and support of members of this site.  What is obvious to you can never be obvious to a beginner.  And we see enough 'obvious' problems on this site to know that even a beginner who is not self-teaching will make rather 'obvious' mistakes.  I'll even add that, on this site, we do see 'classically training' srudents who are trying to get their entire homework done by someone else.  This simply does not happen with self-teaching students, does it?

Comment: @Michaël Roy he's not teaching himself, because his guide is ultimately developed by someone else, whether that's his compiler, his hardware, his manual, etc. It all comes from other people. If he developed this all from the ground up, sure, he doesn't need a guide. But he didn't develop electricity, so he best listen when his guide tell him not to put knives in the wall socket. Programming C can be dangerous, put lives at risk etc. Some of the portability issues are so subtle they take years to surface, and by then you might have a THERAC-25 case on your hands.

Comment: @autistic  The firsst and best developers of the time learned by trial and error.  Sometimes, they documented stuff that works... All of the time, stuff that works is still in their code.  And, again, this empiical way of doing is the driving reason why this website exists.  Happy new year.

Answer (score 0):

when the called function plans to (directly) change anything in the caller function, pass the address of the item to the called function. I.E.

```
int main( void ) 
{
    struct Students S1;
    pasteInfo_1( &S1 );   // <-- passing pointer to struct
    printStudents( S1 );
}
```

Then modify the pasteInfo_1()` function to expect a pointer,

```
void pasteInfo_1( struct Students * pS1 ) 
{
    strcpy( pS1->lastName, "Effinger" );
}
```

Note the use of vertical alignment of the braces and the use of appropriate horizontal spacing.

The purpose of the vertical alignment and horizontal spacing is to make the code much more readable.

Comment: I tried that, but make then printed several errors:
"warning: 'struct Students' declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declarations void pasteInfo(struct Students * pS1);"
It printed the same for printStudents
"Warning: passing argument one of 'pasteInfo' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types] pasteInfo( &S1 );

Comment: @Jordan, Your comment sounds like you edited out the actual definition of the struct, which (in general) should be inserted immediately after the `#include` statements

Comment: I kept the definition of the struct. (But I did learn that prototypes go after structs)